# Angular2 routing: auxiliary routes not working for lazy loaded modules

Tags: angular, angular2-routing

I'm trying to implement a basic aux route setup, inspired by a demo I found on  [this plunk](https://plnkr.co/edit/e5eK0ksB08GXzIRCyInr?p=preview).

I have an app module, which lazy loads the main module.

This is my app-routing module:

```
const routes: Routes = [{
    path: '',
    loadChildren: 'app/main/main.module#MainModule',
    canActivate: [AuthenticationGuard],
}, {
    path: 'login',
    component: LoginComponent,
    canDeactivate: [PreventUnsavedChangesGuard]
}, {
    path: 'foo',
    component: FooComponent,
    outlet: 'side',
}, {
    path: 'home',
    redirectTo: '/',
    pathMatch: 'full',
}, {
    path: '**',
    component: PageNotFoundComponent
}];
```

And here's my app.component.html:

```
<router-outlet>
</router-outlet>

<p>Side:</p>

<router-outlet name='side'>
</router-outlet>
```

Now when I enter in my adress bar:

> http://localhost:4200/login(side:foo)

everything works as expected.

---

I'm using an extremely similar setup in my lazy-loaded main module.

main.routing.ts:

```
{
    path: 'main',
    component: MainComponent,

},

{
    path: 'red',
    component: RedComponent,

}, {
    path: 'green',
    component: GreeenComponent,
    outlet: 'color'
}, {
    path: 'blue',
    component: BlueComponent
},
```

main.component.html:

```
<router-outlet></router-outlet>

<p>Color:<p>
<router-outlet name="color"></router-outlet>
```

But it's not working. I can't get my GreenComponent to show in my named router outlet. I'm getting an error:

> Error: Cannot match any routes. URL Segment: 'green'

Can anyone help?

Comment: Probably connected to this issue: https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/15033